# Generic way to map one type of nested array of object to another type of nested array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have one source array let's say.

```
[{ id: 1
   name: 'one'
   ...other-properties
   children: [{ 
                 id: 1.1,
                 name: 'one.one',
                 ...other-properties
                 children: [ upto n levels... ]
              }]
}]
```

and I have one destination array, let's say.

```
[{ value: 1
   label: 'one'
   ...other-properties
   childs: [{ 
                 value: 1.1,
                 label: 'one.one',
                 ...other-properties
                 childs: [ upto n levels... ]
              }]
}]
```

in above source and destination names can be any. and keys can be of any number. so is there possibility to create generic function which can map source data to destination data?

Comment: where is the specific problem?

Comment: Looks like all you're doing is changing the name of the keys.

Comment: I updated and corrected some errors in question. is it clear or still I am confusing?

Comment: @HereticMonkey. ya. it is it.

Comment: because I am using 3rd party libraries. which accepts different names then I get from database fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const map = ({ id, name, ...rest, children }) => ({ value: id, label: name, ...rest, childs: children.map(map), });
```

You can use object destructuring and recursion to map one version to the other.